# Uninitialized Constant Admin::ClientsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a admin namespace i have configured the routes.rb as follows

```
  namespace "admin" do
    root :to => "home#index"
    resources  :projects
    resources  :clients
    resources  :tasks
  end
```

and i have folder structure as follows
`controllers/admin/clients/clients_controller.rb`
and class named `Admin::ClientsController < ApplicationController`
and the error is

> Routing Error
>
> uninitialized constant Admin::ClientsController
> Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably put your controller to `controllers/admin/clients_controller.rb`